# When does l1 regularisation give a sparse solution?

Tags: convex-optimization, estimation, regularization

I was maximising a likelihood function, which is convex. I know that the system has a K-sparse solution. I wanted to know the conditions (or some sufficient conditions) on the likelihood function under which l1-regularisation is guaranteed to give me the sparse solution.

In other words, I am trying to solve the following problem

$$\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x),$$

where $f$ is a concave function. However I know that the true solution is K-sparse. I wanted to know the conditions under which the following optimisation returns the correct solution

$$\max_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x) - \lambda ||x||_1.$$

I found online that if $f=||y-Ax||_2^2$, then we need $A$ to satisfy a property called the restricted eigenvalue property. I wanted to know if anything is known in the general case or even special cases where such guarantees were known.

Comment: Just to clarify, wouldn't this also depend on the value of $\lambda$? So you'd need a condition to check if a $\lambda$ exists for which the solutions are equivalent, and presumably also a method to compute such a $\lambda$ right?

Comment: @wonko My (limited) understanding is that $\lambda$ is usually tuned as a parameter. The existence of a $\lambda$ is essential to this, but I do not think people are worried about computing such a $\lambda$.